# How to implement the autotesting stage in GitLab CI using CodeceptJS?

Tags: gitlab-ci, codeceptjs

I am trying to configure the startup stage of autotests in the GitLab CI pipeline according to the example:

[CodeceptJS GitLab Integration](https://codecept.discourse.group/t/codeceptjs-gitlab-integration/427)

Step to reproduce:

1. I cloned this repository https://gitlab.com/paulvincent/codeceptjs-e2e-testing

```
git@gitlab.com:paulvincent/codeceptjs-e2e-testing.git
```

2. added changes and make a push

As a result, the Job filed with error

[image]

[image]

If someone has set up CodeceptJS + Gitlab CI, please share the config **.gitlab-ci.yml**

Comment: In your second screenshot on line 77, you're showing 1 failed tests. This would seem to indicate that your tests are running successfully, but that the one e2e test that is written has failed with an error. The error message above (`mceu_3 was not found`) seems to indicate a missing element (or a bad ID selector, since it's prefixed with `#`). Are you sure this is a CI problem, and not a problem with your test?

Comment: @Patrick  Thank you very much! You were absolutely right.I commented out the problem area, committed the changes and the test was successfully passed

Comment: Perfect, I'll go ahead and leave that as an answer so you can accept it to close the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're not experiencing an issue with GitLab, so much as you have a failing test. On line 77 of your image, it shows a test failing based on not finding the `mceu_3` id. Once you resolve that test, your job should complete successfully.

Note that if you want to add a test result (such as a junit result) into your merge request, you'll want to set `when:always` on the artifact for the job so it collects the report even when the job fails!